# Cell heights "wrong on load" when changing heights at runtime

Tags: ios, ios8, autolayout, ios9, nslayoutconstraint

My current project nicely shows **changing the height of cells, when you select a cell**<sup>1</sup>. Everything is perfect.

But, in my current code, when you first **launch the app**, the heights are wrong.

As soon as you select/unselect some rows or perhaps scroll, everything is perfect.

[image]

I can't find the problem. Already tried `tableView.reloadData()` in `viewDidAppear`, doesn't help. Any ideas?  What could cause this?

---

<sup>1</sup> *By the way if you're just starting with autolayout the example data is from the popular demo of how to make a (static) variable height cell at: [appcoda](http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 0), withRowAnimation: .Automatic)`

instead of `reloadData()`

Comment: viewDidAppear will be called before pulling the data . use in refreshPulled() after you fetch the data .. or tableView.beginupdate()/endupdate()

Comment: I used it in model class method, that triggers on setting in ivar (and it triggers on pullToRefresh). However, you can always use search to find all reloadData methods.

Comment: It solved the problem in your demo project. I don't know what you have in your actual project.

Comment: **It works!!** That really seems like a screw-up from Apple to me.  Good one!  bounty en route ...